# Subir una imagen desde React a Node

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, filesystem

Tengo un problema al intentar subir una imagen tanto a mi servidor local, como a Cloudinary. Los endpoints los estoy probando en POSTMAN, y efectivamente, al mandar un archivo en form-data, con la key, y subiendo el archivo, si se sube todo exitosamente, y puedo ver los cambios en mongodb

El problema esta cuando intento subir ese archivo desde mi app de react usando exactamente el mismo endpoint, creo que hay algun problema de como estoy mandando el archivo, no se si es la forma correcta, pero la mayoria de los tutoriales lo hacen así (modifique mi codigo de ejemplo para que se vea claramente todo el error.)

```
 const handleIMG = (e) => {

const file = e.target.files[0];

console.log(file)

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('img', file);

fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/uploads/productos/1684592896346", {
  method: 'PUT',
  body: formData,
```

})

```
const fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
fileReader.addEventListener('load', (e) => {
  setImagePreview(e.target.result);
});
```

}; Nota: Mediante un onChange obtengo la imagen de un input de tipo file, si le paso un console.log a ese file da esto [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el error en consola de NODE

> Cita en bloque SyntaxError: Unexpected token - in JSON at position 0
> at JSON.parse ()
> at createStrictSyntaxError (C:\Users\Ulacio\Desktop\Backend\server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:160:10)
> at parse (C:\Users\Ulacio\Desktop\Backend\server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)
> at C:\Users\Ulacio\Desktop\Backend\server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:128:18
> at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:204:9)
> at invokeCallback (C:\Users\Ulacio\Desktop\Backend\server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:231:16)
> at done (C:\Users\Ulacio\Desktop\Backend\server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:220:7)
> at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\Ulacio\Desktop\Backend\server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:280:7)
> at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)